# Passing variables to function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code in the body

```
<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="changeMarker(marker1)">
```

and the following in the head

```
function changeMarker(marker) {
    alert(marker);
}
```

Now when i mouseover the div, I get the following error in the javascript console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: marker1 is not defined
```

If I have the following instead, where the function does not take variables, the alert box is called.

```
function changeMarker() {
    alert('hi');
}

<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="changeMarker()">
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

**EDIT**

I forgot I defined marker1 within initialize() as follows (I'm using google maps v3 api)

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  

                position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

                map: map,

                icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|c41200|ffffff"

            });
```

This is the rest of the code I'm really using:

```
<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="changeMarker(marker1)">
```

and the function is

```
function changeMarker(marker) {
            var icon = new Google.maps.MarkerImage({ url:"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200"});
            marker.setIcon(icon);
        }
```

I get the same error:     Uncaught ReferenceError: marker1 is not defined

Comment: you never defined `marker1` anywhere so how does it know what to pass? You never told it what the variable `marker1` is. If you are trying to send a string to your function then it needs quotes around it: `<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="changeMarker('marker1')">`

Comment: Is `marker1` defined global? Is it in a `script` tag that comes before the `div` tag?

Comment: yes marker1 and the changeMarker function is defined within script tag that is in the head... how do I make marker1 global?

Comment: marker1 is defined within the initialize() function, which is called     <body onLoad="initialize()">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work properly:

```
<script>
    function changeMarker(marker) {
        alert(marker);
    }

    var marker1 = 'Test Data';
</script>

<style>
    #searchresult {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="changeMarker(marker1)">
    Test Box
</div>
```

---

Something like this however, will not work, because `marker1`'s scope is limited to the google callback.

```
<script>                                                                                     
    function changeMarker(marker) {                                                          
        alert(marker);                                                                       
    }                                                                                        

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {                                                    
        var marker1 = 'Test Data';
    });
</script>
```

To Fix this, you might do:

```
<script>                                                                                     
    function changeMarker(marker) {                                                          
        alert(marker);                                                                       
    }                                                                                   

    var marker1;

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {                                                    
        marker1 = 'Test Data';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: will it work if i make the marker1 variable global? how do i make it global?

Comment: I added an additional piece of code. I'm not great at javascript, so there may be a nicer way of doing that, but I've included a simple way.

Comment: I tried that and I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Google is not defined

Comment: This is likely a different problem. Perhaps you are not loading the google jsapi properly?

Comment: I got rid of the Google error... its because I capitalised google in the changeMarker function

Comment: Now I get the error: GET localhost/mysite/places/[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I got rid of var icon and placed the url directly in marker.setIcon(). I'm not sure why this works though...

Answer (score 1):

> I forgot I defined marker1 within initialize()

Then it is scoped to `initialize` and not accessible in the wider scope.

You could drop the `var` to make it a global, but you would probably be better off assigning your event handler with JS inside `initialize` instead of using HTML attributes to do it.

Comment: i tried dropping the 'var' as u suggested and got the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Google is not defined'...

Comment: I'd have to see the entire code to figure out why that was happening. Go with the approach I said was better in the first place. Use JS to attach event handlers.

Comment: I tried adding the following code inside initialize():

document.getElementById("searchresult").onmouseover= function() {changeMarker(marker1);}

I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Google is not defined

Comment: When I use the following it works:
document.getElementById("searchresult").onmouseover= function() {location.href="page2.htm";}

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help:

`<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="function(){changeMarker(marker1)}">`

Comment: I assumed (incorrectly?) it existed in code the author didn't share.